# SSIS Multiple File Load Error with Variable

Tags: sql-server, excel, visual-studio, ssis, oledb

I have an SSIS package that is to load multiple Excel files using the For Each Loop Containter.  As soon as I add the variable in the Excel Connection manager in expressions, under ExcelFilePath Property it throws an error in the Excel Source Package:

> An OLEDB error has occurred 0X80004005. The MIcrosoft Access
>   Database Engine cannot write to the file "C:..."

It is already opened exclusively by another user or you need permission. I had to already download the 32bit Extension to be able to view the Excel files.   I've followed many guides on how to do this, and it always ends up in the same result. Delay validations are set to True.   Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Are you running the package in 64 or 32 bit runtime?

Comment: I've tried both 32 and 64. I.e. I've made True and False on Run64BitRunTime in project menu under debugger.

Comment: It is the exclusive access to the file issue. You looks like attempting to write to the same file you're reading @Ginger22

Comment: https://www.mattmasson.com/2013/04/error-the-microsoft-access-database-engine-cannot-open-or-write-to-the-file/

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots of the data flow task, excel expression and for each loop container configuration?